# Docusign API and Integrator Key certification questions

Tags: docusignapi, apex

I have couple of questions regarding the docusign api and its Integrator Key Certification

1. I'm using REST API calls for Docusign Integration with Salesforce;
   We need Endpoint, UserId, AccountId, Password, Integrator key for Docusign REST API calls. Every value of these fields for different users are stored in Docusign managed objects of salesforce except Integrator Key. 
   Need of one Integrator Key is making me to either go for harcoding these credentials/use custom settings of Salesforce. Anyone suggest a better way for other than this?
2. So what I did For Authentication header is, (Though it may seem like not a best practice I have no other way to do)
   I have accessed the user credentials from custom settings of Salesforce. But in-order to overcome the limit of 1000 API calls per 
   hour per account, I am thinking to use multiple user credentials which are changing one after the other for every api call. 
   So, Will docusign allow the  multiple Integrator Keys Certification that are used in one single apex class?

For those who are thinking about baseURL parameter in authentication header, I will go with the "/login_information/" api call, (or) change the value from custom settings depending on environment where the api is called.

Using, all this logic my task is working perfectly but all of sudden I am thinking will Docusign allow to pass certification for the above Integration steps? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question should be emailed to apicertifications@docusign.com as listed as the support contact on this page https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/go-live/certification.

Answer (score 2):

As Andrew has mentioned in his comments, you should reach out to DocuSign's Certification department with any certification questions you may have.  However, I can still provide some info for you here:

1. It's really up to you and your security and business requirements how you want to store your application's Integrator Key; however I can tell you that I've seen numerous other integrations do it by hard-coding the value into a PRIVATE apex class. Private so that no other objects can access it.
2. No, DocuSign will not allow multiple Integrator Keys in this instance.  When you go through and pass the Certification process, the result is that just ONE of your demo IKs are promoted to production environment.  That one integrator key represents your entire integration.